# xarray: replace array values corresponding to particular dates in datetime

Tags: datetime, python-datetime, python-xarray

I have an example array of zeros:

```
time = np.arange('2000', '2005', dtype='datetime64[D]')
test_array = xr.DataArray(np.zeros(len(time)), coords={'time': time}, dims=['time'])
```

Now if I have some data e.g. `test_data = np.ones(365)` that I want to put into the array corresponding to year `2001` (which has 365 days) how do I go about doing this?

I want to do something like: `test_array[test_array.where(time='2001')] = test_data` but `.where()` here doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works, but if there is a more elegant way I'd love to know.

```
ind_start = (test_array.indexes['time'] == pd.Timestamp('2001-01-01')).argmax()
ind_end = (test_array.indexes['time'] == pd.Timestamp('2001-12-31')).argmax()
test_array[ind_start:ind_end + 1] = test_data
```

Answer (score 0):

The three-argument [`xarray.where`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.where.html) function could be a more elegant alternative:

```py
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

times = pd.date_range('2000', '2002')
da = xr.DataArray(range(len(times)), [('time', times)])
result = xr.where(da.time.dt.year == 2001, 1, da)
```

It works with arrays of values too:

```py
ones = xr.ones_like(da)
result = xr.where(da.time.dt.year == 2001, ones, da)
```

If you are starting from a pure NumPy array, you'll need to cast it to a `DataArray` and make sure that its time coordinate aligns exactly with the time coordinate of `da`; if the initial length of the NumPy array differs from that of `da`, you'll need to add a reindexing step.  Here's one way to do that:

```py
import numpy as np

year_2001_times = da.time.sel(time=da.time.dt.year == 2001)
arr = np.random.random(len(year_2001_times))

random_da = xr.DataArray(arr, [('time', year_2001_times)])
reindexed_random_da = random_da.reindex_like(da)

result = xr.where(da.time.dt.year == 2001, reindexed_random_da, da)
```

Comment: Generally how could I do this with any numpy array of length 365 (not necessarily ones) `arr` using `result = xr.where(da.time.dt.year == 2001, arr, da)`? If I try to do this while `arr` is a 365-long np array I get a broadcasting ValueError. If I need to manually convert `arr` to an xr format how should I do this so that it is compatible?

Comment: Indeed starting from a pure NumPy array in this case is a little more cumbersome; see my latest update.  Do you think you could find a way to generate the length-365 array such that it was already appropriately labeled with dates from 2001 and in the form of a `DataArray`? Then all you would need is the reindexing step before passing it to `where`.